# Uninstall django-modeltranslation

Tags: django, django-modeltranslation

We've decided that with Chrome's page translation support, it's too much work to keep up with the translation of the entire site for the benefit received. So, I need to remove/uninstall [django-modeltranslation app](https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and am wondering what's the recommended path forward? When the app was added, tables in the database were modified to add a new field for each language. However, those are not listed in the model so I can't just modify the model...

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pip you can uninstall it :

```
pip uninstall django-modeltranslation
```

Remove modeltranslation from installed apps in your settings.py and to remove database tables for this app you can run this command:

```
./manage.py reset modeltranslation
```

That's all !

Answer (score 0):

Current state of django and modeltranslations:

1. Remove "modeltranslation" from `INSTALLED_APPS`
2. `python manage.py makemigrations`
3. `python manage.py migrate`

Don't forget to replace translated fields calls in code!